# How to tell your program which file you want to read C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void read();

int main() {
   read();
   return 0;
}




void read () {
   string file("");
   string nameOfFile("");
   cin >> nameOfFile;
   ifstream in (nameOfFile);
   while ( !in.eof() ) {
    getline(in, file);
    cout << file;
    cout << endl;
}
cout << file;
in.close();
}
```

How come this isn't working, I'm trying to make it so i can type in which file i want to read?

I'm really new to C++, sorry if this is an obvious fix.

Comment: first dont do while(!in.eof) - many SO posts on this

Comment: second - what goes wrong? What did u see when you ran it with the debugger?

Comment: 'In' Was not Declared in this scope,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to open the ifstream usign `in.open()`, and hendle the case where file does not exist as well. here is the function:

```
void read() {
    string file("");
    string fileContent = "";
    string nameOfFile("");
    cin >> nameOfFile;
    ifstream in(nameOfFile.c_str());
    in.open(nameOfFile, ios::in);
    if (in){
        while (!in.eof()) {
            getline(in, file);
            fileContent += file;
        }
        cout << fileContent;
        in.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not open file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i never expected this community to be so friendly

Comment: This code does not compile, and this does not answer the problem of the OP.

Comment: @Shaurya, i am using VS 2013 and it is working fine on my machine. Perhaps you have some other version of VS or the problem is else where.

Comment: OP had a `in was not declared in this scope` error. That is,  the constructor parameter was wrong as ifstream's constructor takes a `char *` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: The typecasting from `char *` to `std::string` is happening automatically in VS2013 for `ifstream`. I tried changing it using your solution of adding the `.c_str()` function as well. But i did not find any difference in output.

Comment: @ShauryaChats: You're referring to `ifstream` as it was defined 11 years ago. Today it does take a `std::string`.

Comment: I compiled using `gcc 4.9.2` but I got the same error OP has, that is, there is no constructor of ifstream accepting a `std::string`. Please check this. http://ideone.com/OaBHST, same result on ideone.com .

Comment: I have updated as you have requested. I have no change in the output with or without adding `c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
ifstream in (nameOfFile);
```

with

```
ifstream in (nameOfFile.c_str());
```

because the default constructor for `ifstream` does not accept a `std::string` as an argument, it needs a `char *`. Hence, use the function `std::string::c_str()` to convert a `std::string` into a `char *`.

Comment: You can use `std::string` in C++11.

Comment: @KyleMcCarthy if you could tell me what was missing in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

A little feedback:

```
void read () {
   string file("");        // you don't need the ("") bit; empty by default,
                           //   and "file" is a terrible choice of identifier as
                           //   it sounds more like an ifstream than a string
                           //   used to hold one line from the file.
                           //   I tend to use "string line;" for this.
   string nameOfFile("");  // ditto
   cin >> nameOfFile;      // you should test for success of input, like this:
                           //   if (!cin >> nameOfFile) {
                           //       std::cerr << "error reading filename from stdin\n";
                           //       exit(1);
                           //   }
   ifstream in (nameOfFile); // test for success getting file open like this:
                             // if (ifstream in(nameofFile))
                             // {
   while ( !in.eof() ) {     // NEVER check eof before attempting input, instead:
    getline(in, file);       //     while (getline(in, file))
    cout << file;            //         cout << file << endl; // can "chain"
    cout << endl;            // }
                             // else
                             //     std::cerr << "couldn't open " << nameOfFile
                             //         << '\n';
}                            // no need for extra cout nor explicit close, as
cout << file;                // the ifstream destructor closes anyway.
in.close();
}
```